# Horizontal recyclerView with volley NetworkImageView image is not displaying

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, networkimageview

I use a RecyclerAdapter to load a lot of images in horizontal view using NetworkImageView(Volley). I am changing the position of recycler view periodically. Some time while scrolling image is not displaying and showing white space instead of original image.

Adapter onBindViewHolder code:

```
    mImageLoader.get(newsDto.getImage(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.networkImageView,
            R.drawable.loading, android.R.drawable                                            
                    .ic_dialog_alert));  

holder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(newsDto.getImage(), mImageLoader);
```

How I am periodically changing position:

```
 new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (getActivity() != null && recyclerView != null) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (adapter.getItemCount() == (lastVisibleItemPosition + 1)) {
                                recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
                            } else {
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, 0, 30000);
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did u get any solution? I am also getting this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso for loading images in ImageView,

```
ImageView imageview_obj;
 Picasso.with(activity).load(newsDto.getImage()).noFade().into(imageview_obj);
```